# Check if there is punctuation or number in the middle of a word

Tags: python, regex, string

For example, I'm trying to have a boolean function if a word has not only letters but also has either number or punctuation or both. If there is only punctuation that exists at the end and no number, it should return False.

1. g3n3rator --> return True
2. 0ffer --> return True
3. Work!ng --> return True
4. morning --> return False
5. hello? --> return False
6. hell0? --> return True

Comment: `not str.isalpha()` should do.

Answer (score 1):

For your solution, you can always use `regex`. As of a non-regex way, try

```
def check(inp):
    if inp.isalpha():
        return False
    if not any(char.isdigit() for char in inp) and inp[-1] in string.punctuation:
        return False
    return True
```

This outputs correct values to all the test cases given in the problem statement. Hope this helps!